# Cannot get types by custom attributes across assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i am attempting to create a basic widget plugin system within my app and i am currently at a sticking point where built in widgets that use my `WidgetAttribute` attribute class (compiled into the exe) work fine, but i cant seem to find any widgets in any of the test plugins i have written.

i am using the following code to load the assemblies:

```
    public static void LoadAll()
    {
        String[] m_filenames = Directory.GetFiles("plugins", "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (String fn in m_filenames)
        {
            Load(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + fn);
        }
    }

    public static void Load(String filename)
    {
        Assembly m_asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
        PluginAssemblies.Add(m_asm);
    }
```

and then the following code to get all types that have my attribute that denotes a widget and its meta data:

```
    public static void LoadAllWidgets()
    {
        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            LoadAllWidgets(assembly);
        }

        foreach (Assembly assembly in PluginLoader.PluginAssemblies)
        {
            LoadAllWidgets(assembly);
        }
    }

    public static void LoadAllWidgets(Assembly asm)
    {
        foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
        {
            WidgetAttribute[] m_attribs = (WidgetAttribute[])type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<WidgetAttribute>().ToArray();
            if (m_attribs.Length > 0)
            {
                WidgetsByGuid.Add(m_attribs[0].ID, type);
                WidgetNamesByGuid.Add(m_attribs[0].ID, m_attribs[0].Name);
                WidgetShowInMenuByGuid.Add(m_attribs[0].ID, m_attribs[0].ShowInMenu);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i call the LoadAllWidgets for the second time (ie. loading the widgets that come from other assemblies), i get the type within the type array, but then GetCustomAttributes returns an empty array.

The attribute is defined as follows, and the same source file is used in both projects:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection; 

namespace WSW.Classes
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class WidgetAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Boolean ShowInMenu { get; set; }

    public WidgetAttribute(String guid, String name, Boolean showmenu)
    {
        Name = name;
        ID = Guid.Parse(guid);
        ShowInMenu = showmenu;
    }

    public WidgetAttribute(String guid, String name)
    {
        Name = name;
        ID = Guid.Parse(guid);
        ShowInMenu = true;
    }
}
}
```

can anyone tell me why i cannot get custom attributes from a type outside of my assembly, even though i have loaded it and can see the type?

**EDIT** a plugin class in the other assembly is defined as follows:

```
[WSW.Classes.WidgetAttribute("{42544B13-7353-40FD-B1D8-DA46A247110A}", "Testimonials")]
public partial class Testimonials : UserControl
{
    public Testimonials()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identity of a type in .Net is {Assembly Name + type name}.

So since you are using *"the same source file is used in both projects"* that means there 2 different attributes in 2 different assemblies (which happen to have the same name). So ether assembly will not be able to see attributes from another assembly easily (both will see attributes, just comparing will not work the way you want).

Solutions:

- make sure each shared attribute is compiled into only one assembly and that assembly used by all consumers of the attribute.
- compare names of attributes, not types.

The same consideration applies for other cases when type identity is used. I.e. if interface is shared between 2 assemblies as source copy than these interface and classes that implement them will not be considered compatible.

So often all shared shared types/interfaces/enumeration for program and related assemblies in are places into shared assembly together. Such assembly can also be considered public API and shared with external components that are designed to integrate with your program.

Note that as soon as you share assembly with someone else it means you need versioning story as many changes (i.e. renaming of a type/method) to shared assembly will cause dependent assemblies to fail to load or malfunction.

Comment: so say, create a seperate project named sdk or something of that name that contains my interfaces and attributes i need, and use that sdk as a reference in both the main app and the plugin?

Comment: @bizzehdee - yes. Good point on other cases like interfaces - you'll get into exactly the same issue as you see with attributes if you use source copy instead of assembly reference.

Comment: ok, created the sdk library and linked it to both sides as a reference, everything works perfectly now, could you edit your answer to make the sdk reference slightly more clear for others and ill accept.